# How to associate the last image from gallery to user's profile picture

Tags: 7, users, media

In Drupal 7  (Commons 7.x-3.46).

I've created a new content type, by which each user can upload images and build a personal picture-gallery.

How can I now associate the last-uploaded-image to the user's profile-picture?

Amodule-based solution is preferable. Is there a better way of doing this, ie without a new content type? Essentially I'm looking for a user-friendly way for users to upload and show their profile pictures.

Comment: Enable **[field collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection) module** and 
 **[field permission](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module**.

Create collection field with an image type and set its number cordiality to unlimited and then add this field collection in `/admin/config/people/accounts/fields` (you can also set its cordiality).

While adding field collection field in `/admin/config/people/accounts/fields` you will see the new permissions block and you can control who can add/view/update this field collection.

Comment: The above comment only to show the all images for current user..

Comment: Thank you for your comment. This is an interesting approach, but I've come across a few problems:
The profile picture isn't taken from the field collection field. It is ignored.
An image field in the account settings is possible, but even then I needed the user_picture_field module to do the bridging. It works, but only with an image field, not with a collection field.
The field_permissions module uses roles. In my case I'm working with flags, ie a user's photos can be viewed only by users flagged with an "i trust this person" flag.
regards,
d

Comment: I've found the  user_picture_field module  almost does it. But it only works with image fields in the user entity or in the profile2 entity. How can I tweak it to work with another content type?

Comment: I have posted the answer, please follow the steps and let me know if it works. Thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Amodule-based solution is preferable. Is there a better way of doing this,
>   ie without a new content type? Essentially I'm looking for a user-friendly
>   way for users to upload and show their profile pictures.

I would like to recommend [field_collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection) module as I already mentioned in the question's comments.

**Step # 1:** Enable [field_collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection) module.

**Step # 2:** go to `/admin/config/people/accounts/fields` and add a new field named as **User Gallery** (machine name should be **field_user_gallery**) and choose field type as "Field collection" and save. Note that you can set the field cardinality as you like.

**Step # 2:** Go to `admin/structure/field-collections` and add a new image field named as **Image** (machine name should be **field_image**) and choose field type as "Image" and save. (It might already be added in the existing field list.)

**Step # 3:** Download custom module from [custom_user_profile](https://github.com/usman84/custom_user_profile/archive/master.zip) and extract to your module directory. Make sure extracted directory name is **custom_user_profile** and then enable it.

That's all. I hope it will work for you as works for me.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer. It works! 
In Drupal-Commons it conflicts with the edit_profile module. After running a few patches on that module, and changing the form_id in your custom module to  'edit_profile_user_profile_form'  it now works perfectly.
Thanks again.

Comment: @dnoncoder Glad to know it worked for you and I apologize not to mention such changes. I should have. Thanks

Comment: @dnoncoder, it should be a new question.

Comment: thank you, i have asked a related question here: 
 https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/269002/how-to-upload-profile-picture-directly-from-user-view

Comment: thinking more about this, wouldn't it be easier to flip it around: to leave the profile picture as it is, and to create a new entry in the field collection every time a user changes the profile picture?

Comment: Still haven't found a good solution for this.. I was advised to use the editable fields module for this, but I'm finding it very buggy, in general, and with field-collections and images even more so... Can't get it to work properly. Been trying for days, applying different patches and setups but no luck. Any tips?